# AttributeError: 'TextualSelect' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When running the query below, in sqlalchemy 1.4.18, I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'TextualSelect' object has no attribute 'filter'.

How can I work further with sqlalchemy on TextualSelect objects?, without having to include all possible filtering and such in the original text query.

This is just a minimal example:

````
query = text("""SELECT somecolumn FROM sometable```).columns(somecolumn=String)
subquery = text("""
 SELECT somecolumn FROM someothertable
 WHERE someothercolumn is not null
""").columns(somecolumn=String)
query = query.filter(query, query.c.somecolumn.in_(subquery))
````

Comment: (1)The shown code is syntactically incorrect, just copy and paste the original code. (2)Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.text()` does not produce a selectable object, so it doesn't have `.filter()` or `.where()` methods.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

tbl = sa.Table(
    "tbl",
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
)

txt = sa.text("SELECT id FROM tbl")
print(type(txt))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>

qry = txt.where(tbl.c.id > 1)
# AttributeError: 'TextClause' object has no attribute 'where'
```

However, if you pass that `.text()` object to `.select()` then you can further tweak that selectable:

```py
qry = sa.select(txt)
print(type(qry))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select'>

qry = qry.where(tbl.c.id > 1)
print(qry)
"""
SELECT SELECT id FROM tbl 
FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.id > :id_1
"""
```

(BTW, with SQLAlchemy 1.4+ `.where()` is preferred over `.filter()`.)

Comment: `sa.select(txt).c` contains no columns information. Can we add this metadata manually?

Comment: Yes, use .columns method. It accepts variable list of arguments in form of <column_name>=<Type>